# Breadcrumb separator is not showing consistently

Tags: module, front-end, breadcrumbs

Not all of the breadcrumb values are properly separated by a slash on my site.  The delimiting slash is present between the first and second crumb, but gone on the next resulting in the second and third words being smashed together.

See these examples:

- http://elacebron.dipucuenca.es/index.php/layout/layout-4
- http://elacebron.dipucuenca.es/index.php/k2/contact

[image]
I have unsucessfully tried changing some options in the following configuration:

- Login as admin user in the dashboard:
- Extensions -> Module Manager -> breadcrumbs module
- Find the Text Separator setting -> Put some string  -> Save

But no changes appear for this specific parameter.

Breadcrums module:
Module  3.0.0, July 2006, joomla!

[image]

Comment: Is your template possibly using a template override for this module?

Comment: @Mirl as I said on your earlier question, we need to know more about the extensions that are active and may be to blame.

Comment: The generated source code for your website shows that the first "divider" is written as expected but the next expected divider is absent and an unused class of `separator` is used.  `<ul class="breadcrumb">
 <li><a href="/index.php">Inicio</a><span class="divider">/</span></li><li class="separator">Gentes</li><li class="active">Noticias</li></ul>`  Has there been a lot of "fiddling around" with your site?  Do you have a few extensions that are due for an upgrade?

Comment: A couple of other things I noticed about your site wen looking into this is that the Breadcrumb does seem to be working as designed in that it is showing the different levels of menus as you proceed down each level, just as @mickmackusa points out your separator is getting mangled. The other thing I noticed is your URL's look nothing like the menu or article that you are selecting suggesting that either you or a 3rd extension is doing something non standard. As your site appears to be under construction, I would disable each 3rd party extension one at a time, testing this condition each time.